# Add Place autocomplete field in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places-autocomplete

I am creating a MERN stack application. This app is for cars and every car should have a location. Admin can add location of any car in CarEditScreen.js. file from where you add other car options. I've added PlaceComponent.js and import into CarEdit's screen.js file, but in the browser when I select the place and click the Update button, the browser console becomes two things:

```
"Performance warning! LoadScript has been reloaded unintentionally! You should not pass `libraries` prop as new array. Please keep an array of libraries as static class property for Components and PureComponents, or just a const variable outside of component, or somewhere in config files or ENV variables"


react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
        at input
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73670:5
```

is there any other way to write code for Google Place Autocomplete field or is this enough? Can you help me please how can I fix this?

I show the code below :
**CarEditScreen.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react'
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError } from '../utils';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import PlaceComponent from '../components/PlaceComponent';



const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
            return {...state, loading:true};
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {...state, loading:false};
        case 'FETCH_FAIL':
            return {...state, loading:false};
        case 'UPDATE_REQUEST':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:true};
        case 'UPDATE_SUCCESS':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:false};
        case 'UPDATE_FAIL':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:false};
        case 'UPLOAD_REQUEST':
                return {...state, loadingUpload:true, errorUpload: ''};
        case 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
                return {...state, loadingUpload:false, errorUpload: ''};
        case 'UPLOAD_FAIL':
                return {...state, loadingUpload:false, errorUpload: action.payload};
        default: return state;
    }
};

export default function CarEditScreen() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    const {id:carId} = params;
    const {state} = useContext(Store);
    const {userInfo} = state;
    const [{loading, error, loadingUpdate, loadingUpload}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        loading: true,
        error: '',
    });


    const [mark, setMark] = useState('');
    const [model, setModel] = useState('');
    const [year, setYear] = useState('');
    const [fuelType, setFuelType] = useState('');
    const [transmission, setTransmission] = useState('');
    const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState('');
    const [pricePerDay, setPricePerDay] = useState('');
    const [pricePerHour, setPricePerHour] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState('');
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    const [available, setAvailable] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try{
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_REQUEST'});
                const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/cars/${carId}`);
                setMark(data.mark);
                setModel(data.model);
                setYear(data.year);
                setFuelType(data.fuelType);
                setTransmission(data.transmission);
                setCapacity(data.capacity);
                setPricePerDay(data.pricePerDay);
                setPricePerHour(data.procePerHour);
                setImage(data.image);
                setImages(data.images);
                setCategory(data.category);
                setLocation(data.location);
                setAvailable(data.available);
                setDescription(data.description);
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS'});


            }catch(err) {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_FAIL',
                    payload: getError(err),
                });
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [carId]);

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_REQUEST'});
            await axios.put(
                `/api/cars/${carId}`,
                {
                    _id: carId,
                    mark,
                    model,
                    year,
                    fuelType,
                    capacity,
                    transmission,
                    pricePerDay,
                    pricePerHour,
                    image,
                    images,
                    category,
                    location,
                    available,
                    description
                    
                },
                {
                    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`},
                }
            );
            dispatch({
                type: 'UPDATE_SUCCESS'
            });
            toast.success('Car updated successfully');

        }catch(err){
           toast.error(getError(err));
           navigate('/admin/cars');
        }
    }

  
  

    const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append('file', file);
        try {
          dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_REQUEST' });
          const { data } = await axios.post('/api/upload', bodyFormData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
          });
          dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_SUCCESS' });
          toast.success('Image uploaded successfully. click Update to apply it');
          setImage(data.secure_url);
        } catch (err) {
          toast.error(getError(err));
          dispatch({ type: 'UPLOAD_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
        }
    }

    

  return (
    <Container className='small-container'>
        <Helmet>
            <title>Edit Car ${carId}</title>
        </Helmet>
        <h2>Edit Car {carId}</h2>

        {loading ? (
            <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
        ) : error ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="mark">
                    <Form.Label>Mark</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={mark}
                    onChange={(e)=> setMark(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="model">
                    <Form.Label>Model</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={model}
                    onChange={(e)=> setModel(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="year">
                    <Form.Label>Year</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={year}
                    onChange={(e)=> setYear(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fuelType">
                    <Form.Label>Fuel Type</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={fuelType}
                    onChange={(e)=> setFuelType(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="transmission">
                    <Form.Label>Transmission</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={transmission}
                    onChange={(e)=> setTransmission(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="capacity">
                    <Form.Label>Capacity</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={capacity}
                    onChange={(e)=> setCapacity(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="pricePerDay">
                    <Form.Label>Price Per Day</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={pricePerDay}
                    onChange={(e)=> setPricePerDay(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="pricePerHour">
                    <Form.Label>Price Per Hour</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={pricePerHour}
                    onChange={(e)=> setPricePerHour(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
               
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="image">
                    <Form.Label>Image File</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control 
                    value={image}
                    onChange={(e)=> setImage(e.target.value)}
                    required
                     />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="imageFile">
                   <Form.Label>Upload File</Form.Label>
                   <Form.Control type="file" onChange={uploadFileHandler}></Form.Control>
                   {loadingUpload && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                </Form.Group>
                
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="category">
                    <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={category}
                    onChange={(e)=> setCategory(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="location">
                    <Form.Label>Location</Form.Label>
                   
                   <PlaceComponent
                        value={location}
                        onChange={(e)=> setLocation(e.target.value)}
                   />
                  
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="available">
                <Form.Label>Available</Form.Label>
                
                    <Form.Check 
                    label="true" 
                    value={true}
                    onChange={(e)=> setAvailable(e.target.value)} />

                    <Form.Check 
                    label="false" 
                    value= {false}
                    onChange={(e)=> setAvailable(e.target.value)} />

                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="description">
                    <Form.Label>Desription</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e)=> setDescription(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <div className='mb-3'>
                    <Button disabled={loadingUpdate} type="submit">Update</Button>
                    {loadingUpdate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                </div>
            </Form>
        )
    }
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**PlaceComponent.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import {StandaloneSearchBox, LoadScript} from '@react-google-maps/api';

export default function PlaceComponent() {

    const inputRef = useRef();
    const handlePlaceChanged = () => {
        const [place] = inputRef.current.getPlaces();
        if(place){
            console.log(place.formatted_address);
            console.log(place.geometry.location.lat());
            console.log(place.geometry.location.lng());
        }
    };

  return (
    <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey = '***********************'
        libraries = {['places']}
    >
        <StandaloneSearchBox
            onLoad={ref => (inputRef.current = ref)}
            onPlacesChanged={handlePlaceChanged}
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                className='form-control'
                placeholder='Enter Location'
            />
        </StandaloneSearchBox>

    </LoadScript> 
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you atleast put comments in your code? Or you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a working codesandbox link that the community can play around with and debug to help you with your concern.